# Pidgin not working with Gtalk

Tags: windows-7, pidgin, google-talk

I have downloaded latest Pidgin(version 2.10.6) for Windows and tried to gtalk account to it. It shows "not authorized" error.

I have tried many options given in the net and its not working for me, Below are the values I have given,

Basic Tab:

```
Protocal: XMPP
Username: <my username>
Domain: gmail.com
Password: <My Password>
```

and enabled Remember password check box

Advanced Tab:

```
Connection security: Require Encryption (Default)
Unhecked "Allow plaintext auth over unencrypted streams" (Default)
Connection Port: 5222 (Default)
Connect server: talk.google.com
File Transfer proxies: proxy.eu.jabber.org (default)
BOSH URL: <Empty> (default)
```

I enabled two step verification process for my gmail account, So I created application specific password and given here. But Its not working.

Please help me what could be the problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: I compared them to my own settings and everything looks the same. Maybe you could add `home` as resource (between domain and password). But that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: No Luck :(, It works for facebook, but not for gtalk

Comment: Actually I have two step verification process, So I had problem with gtalk, So I created application specific password from settings page and given in gtalk it was working, But its not working for pidgin. :(

Comment: What about temporary disable two-step verification, test pidgin and re-enable two-step verification? Just to see if this causes your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using a 2-step authentication, you'll need the application specific password that you can get from:

> Google > Account > Security > Authorising applications

Answer (score -1):

Just spent a few hours struggling to get Pidgin work with 2-step verification. It looks like Google Accounts website structure has been changed, making all the instructions and links on the web outdated. It's especially misleading that Manage Apps and App Passwords are two different sections.

**Updated Guide for Adding App Specific Passwords to Google Account**

Here's how to navigate to App Passwords section:

```
Google Accounts > Signing in to Google > App Passwords
```

Or use the direct link below:

```
https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords
```

Comment: I can't tell — is this supposed to be an answer, or it is an “I’m having this problem, too” comment?

Comment: @Scott Explaining oneself can be difficult at times. Tried to make it less ambiguous.